# check if radio button is not empty

Tags: jquery

```
radio = $('input:radio[name=priority]:checked').val();

// if radio hv checked
if(radio !== ""){
 // do something
}
```

this doesn't work, what should be inside my if statement? I tried other field like username !=="" it work fine, but not for the radio field..

Comment: What do you want to check? if the radio is checked? what's the value of the checked radio button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using `is`:

```
// if radio hv checked
if($('input:radio[name=priority]').is(':checked')){
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if the radio button is checked, and the value property is set, it will return the value. Your code is trying to get the value of the checked radio button. Try the code below.

```
radio = $('input:radio[name=priority]').val();
```

**EDIT:** Okay, this should do it for radio button validation.

```
if ($('input:radio[name=priority]').is(':checked') { }
```

Comment: actually that's what I want, I want to do a validation where user cannot pass through if no radio is checked

Comment: @MiguelaAnthony I've edited my answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: is(':checked') vs is('checked'), what is the diff?

Comment: @MiguelaAnthony that was a typo. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`$('input:radio[name=priority]:checked').val();` returns `undefined` if there are no checked radio buttons, since your are using `!==` your if condition succeeds because `undefined !== ''`

A possible solution is to check the number of checked radios as given below

```
var $radiosc = radio = $('input:radio[name=priority]:checked');
if($radiosc.length){
    var radio = $radiosc.val();
    //do something if selected
}
```

or test of undefined

```
radio = $('input:radio[name=priority]:checked').val();

// if radio hv checked
if(radio !== undefined){
 // do something
}
```

Comment: so how not let the user pass if there are no checkbox is checked?

Comment: @MiguelaAnthony see the updates